Go router Optional pathParameters
In StackOverflow, you can access question through two different URL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/:questionId/:slug
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/:questionId

I am trying to build the Same.
  GoRoute(
            path: "${LeaderboardItemPage.route}/:creationId",
            name: LeaderboardItemPage.route,
            redirect: (
              context,
              state,
            ) {
              final creationId = state.pathParameters['creationId'];
              return "${LeaderboardItemPage.route}/$creationId/overview";
            },
            routes: [
              /// same as a
              GoRoute(
                path: ":slug",
                // pag
                // name: LeaderboardItemPage.route,
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  final creationId = state.pathParameters['creationId'];
                  final slug = state.pathParameters['slug'];
                  print("Slug: $slug");
                  if (creationId == null) {
                    return ErrorWidget();
                  }
                  return LeaderboardItemPage(
                    creationId: creationId,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),

This barely works, but has lots of issue. First of all , I am forcing a dummy slug called overview . What if I actually want it to be null and show a popup to the user asking to create a permalink ?
Secondly,
 context.pushNamed(LeaderboardItemPage.route, pathParameters: {
      'creationId': leaderboardItem.creationId,
      'slug' : "some-slug"
    });
    return;

I get unknown param "slug" for /creations/:creationId. I want to use the same routeName for both and still use the pathParameters, not direct url

Since you want two different links to point to the same location, why not have a GoRoute that can only be visited by the first link; then in your GoRouter, not GoRoute, make use of the redirect so that when the second link is detected it will redirect to the first.

Isn't that what I am doing already ?  redirect: (               context,               state,             ) {               final creationId = state.pathParameters['creationId'];               return "${LeaderboardItemPage.route}/$creationId/overview";             },

Handle the redirect in the GoRouter level, not GoRoute @TSR
